# How to make position a dynamic property of a widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have a class for a widget with one of its properties being its location. I've tried to do this by wrapping it in Align but it just returns a blank page. what's going wrong?

```
class Note extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NoteState createState() => _NoteState();
}

class _NoteState extends State<Note> {
  AudioCache _audioCache;

  List<NoteButton> notes = [
  NoteButton(hori: 5.0, noteName: 'a3.mp3', num: '0', vert: 8.0),
  NoteButton(hori: 8.0, noteName: 'a-3.mp3', num: '0', vert: 4.0)
  ];


  Widget buttonTemplate(NoteButton note){
      return Align(
            alignment: Alignment(note.vert, note.hori),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () => null,
    ),
    );
  }

void initState() {
    super.initState();
  
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home:  Scaffold(
          body: Row(
            children:  notes.map((note) => buttonTemplate(note)).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey have you tried the stack widget:
example:

```
.....
body: Stack(
        children:[
          Positioned(
            top:10,left:20,
            child: Text("Hello 1"),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top:50,left:70,
            child: Text("Hello 2"),
          ),
        ]
      )
.....
```

Point to take home if you intent to animated children in a stack add keys for a smooth experience